# How to add html element in to Angular Component

Tags: angular

I have my custom component like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'panel-top-page',
  template: `
    <div class="border-radius" nz-row [nzGutter]="5">

    </div>
  `,
})
export class PanelTopPageComponent extends BaseValueAccessor implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }
}
```

And I use like this

```
 <panel-top-page nz-col nzFlex="auto" nz-row [nzGutter]="5">
     <div>Here I want to add my html element</div>
 </panel-top-page>
```

And my result don't show and element inside
[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHdXN.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `<ng-content></ng-content>`.

**Example:**

```
<div class="border-radius" nz-row [nzGutter]="5">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```